# Connecting 3rd party nodes to Bitcoinlib

Tags: python, web3py, bitcoind, bitcoinlib

I have this node endpoint that requires JSON-RPC payload:
https://btc.getblock.io/my_api_key/testnet/

I have not been able to connect this node to the Bitcoinlib Python module.

I have tried to connect this node to the Bitcoinlib module. I however have failed thus far in doing so.
Bitcoinlib's built-in AuthServiceProxy is only able to connect to locally hosted nodes (using username and password). How do I establish a connection to this third party node provider in Bitcoinlib with only an API link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot help with connecting to a third-party library, as it is outside our jurisdiction.

But you can try to use the requests library in Python to send HTTP requests to the JSON-RPC endpoint and handle the JSON-RPC payload manually.

Comment: yes, that is what I ended going up with, after thoroughly reading through bitcoin's developer documentation, I was able to write my own small wrapper for generating my keys, addresses, transactions etc.